# How to add a different audio file to each slide for narration?

Tags: vba, audio, powerpoint

I want to add a different audio file to each slide for narration.

I can use the ribbon to insert an audio file for each slide. Manually doing it takes forever.

I can't locate in the VBA PowerPoint docs what object to work with.
When I search for audio, insert audio etc. I get nothing helpful from MS PowerPoint docs.

Comment: This should be `AddMediaObject2` method under `Shapes` object ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addmediaobject2)). Something like `Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddMediaObject2("audio file path")`

Comment: Yes that is what I need! Thanks.

Comment: Good to know that's what you are looking for. I have submitted an answer for future read, please accept it (by clicking the tick beside the answer).

Answer (score 1):

To add audio file, use `AddMediaObject2` method under `Shapes` object. ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addmediaobject2))

Example of adding an audio file to the first slide of your current presentation:

```
Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddMediaObject2("Audio file path")
```

You can also set a variable to the `Shape` returned by the method for further modification:

```
Dim newAudio As Shape
Set newAudio = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddMediaObject2("Audio file path")
```