# Adding picture file and sound file to slide with powerpoint vba from excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Adding picture file and sound file to slide with powerpoint vba from excel...

I was able to make this code piece from the internet. I can add as much milk as I want.

The things I need to add right now are people's pictures and audio files.

I have my own code working. I could not manage to add image and sound to this code.

I actually have a way in mind. maybe it will be helpful. transferring the file address in the relevant cell to a variable and transferring that variable to FileName. but I could not.

Here is the code that I found on the net and rewrote for myself.

```
Sub CreateSlides_Text2()
'create slide for each name in list
'fill two text boxes
Dim myPT As Presentation
Dim myMain As Slide
Dim myDup As Slide

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim wbA As Object
Dim wsA As Object
Dim myList As Object
Dim myRng As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim col01 As Long
Dim col02 As Long
Dim col03 As Long
Dim col04 As Long


'columns with text for slides
col01 = 1
col02 = 2
col03 = 3
col04 = 4
On Error Resume Next
Set myPT = ActivePresentation
Set myMain = myPT.Slides(1)

Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set wbA = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = wbA.ActiveSheet
Set myList = wsA.ListObjects(1)
On Error GoTo errHandler

If Not myList Is Nothing Then
  
  Set myRng = myList.DataBodyRange
  
  For i = 1 To myRng.Rows.Count
    With myPT
      'Duplicate slide 1, move after last slide
      myMain.Duplicate
      Set myDup = .Slides(2)
      myDup.MoveTo myPT.Slides.Count
      
      'change text in 1st textbox
      myDup.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
          = myRng.Cells(i, col01).Value
         
      'change text in 2nd textbox
      myDup.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
          = myRng.Cells(i, col02).Value
          
           'change text in 3nd textbox
      myDup.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
          = myRng.Cells(i, col03).Value
          
           'change text in 4nd textbox
      myDup.Shapes(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
          = myRng.Cells(i, col04).Value
          
      
          
    End With
  Next
Else
  MsgBox "No Excel table found on active sheet"
  GoTo exitHandler
End If

exitHandler:
  Exit Sub
errHandler:
  MsgBox "Could not complete slides"
  Resume exitHandler:
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Adding an audio clip to a slide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69308932/2727437

Comment: Adding a picture to a slide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addpicture

Comment: I believe adding a picture would look something like `myDup.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=myRng.Cells(i, col04).Value2, LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=100, Top:=100`

Comment: thank you very much. The picture part is done, now I'm looking at the sound process.

Comment: I used your code in audio. that's how it was.. thank you very much indeed....

Comment: myDup.Shapes.AddMediaObject2 _
      FileName:=myRng.Cells(i, col04).Value2, _
      LinkToFile:=msoTrue, _
      SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, _
      Width:=300, Height:=200

Comment: If you’ve solved it you can actually post your own work as an answer. I’ll upvote it